# Functional Testing with Jasmine

Tags: testing, jasmine, extjs4.2

Right now, I'm using Jasmine + Karma to write/run unit tests on an ExtJS application I've developed. Because I'm using ExtJS, there's a lot of buttons and forms I would like to write tests for as well. What are some good Jasmine plugins to use to do this? Or would it be worth using something completely different - and if so, what?

Thanks in advance.